# Umbraco macro string into KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, regex, macros, umbraco

I have a string that looks like this:

```
<?UMBRACO_MACRO redirectto="/sagen.aspx" loginpage="/Login.aspx" macroAlias="BrowserValidation" />
```

I want to get a list of `KeyValuePair<string, string>` where the key is the first part and value is the second part. An example would be:

- Key: redirectto Value: /sagen.aspx
- Key: loginpage Value: /Login.aspx
- Key: macroAlias Value: BrowserValidation

Im thinking of using regular expressions but to be honest I don't where to start. I know I can use `\"(.*?)\"` to get the values, but I don't know how to get the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following regex:

```
(?<=\s)([^=]+)="([^"]+)"
```

Here is the code in C#:

```
var input = @"<?UMBRACO_MACRO redirectto=""/sagen.aspx"" loginpage=""/Login.aspx"" macroAlias=""BrowserValidation"" />";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<=\s)([^=]+)=""([^""]+)""");
foreach (Match match in matches) {
    Console.Write(match.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.Write(" : ");
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

and here is a more compact version of the previous code which automatically maps attributes name and value pair to a dictionary:

```
var input = @"<?UMBRACO_MACRO redirectto=""/sagen.aspx"" loginpage=""/Login.aspx"" macroAlias=""BrowserValidation"" />";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<=\s)([^=]+)=""([^""]+)""");
var dictionary = matches.Cast<Match>()
    .Select( m => new {Key = m.Groups[1].Value, Value = m.Groups[2].Value } )
    .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
Console.WriteLine(dictionary);
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jQ8gM1)

Answer (score 1):

... Try this:

```
\s(?<key>.*?)\=\"(?<value>.*?)\"
```

Basically, this will give you 2 named captures:

1. **key** - This has to begin with whitespace and will be any number of characters until the first `="` is encountered
2. **value** - This will be any number of characters until the next `"` is encountered

And your output would be:

```
key: redirectto  ||  value: /sagen.aspx 
key: loginpage  ||  value: /Login.aspx
key: macroAlias  ||  value: BrowserValidation
```

Hope this does the trick!!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
static void Main()
{
    string stringToSearch = @"<?UMBRACO_MACRO redirectto=""/sagen.aspx"" loginpage=""/Login.aspx"" macroAlias=""BrowserValidation"" />";
    string pattern = @"\s(\S+)=""(.+?)""";
    var matches = Regex.Matches( stringToSearch, pattern );
    foreach( Match match in matches )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Key: " + match.Groups[1].ToString() + ". Value: " + match.Groups[2].ToString() );
    }
}
```

Output:

> Key: redirectto. Value: /sagen.aspx
>
> Key: loginpage. Value: /Login.aspx
>
> Key: macroAlias. Value: BrowserValidation

where:

- \s is whitespace
- \S is non-whitespace (assumes no whitespace in key)
- + is 1 or more.
- .+? means match lazily rather than greedily.
- () means group and are refered to later when iterating groups.